# Count multiple rows in JOIN table

Tags: sql, join, count

Parent table:

```
adverts
- id
```

Child table:

```
advertsitems
- id
- advertid
- price
- quantity
```

I'm trying to count the quantity based on the `advertid` but somehow I can't get it working. This is what I have:

```
  SELECT adverts.title AS adtitle, 
         adverts.id AS adid, 
         adverts.image AS image,
         description, 
         price, 
         shipping, 
         customs, 
         createdate
    FROM adverts 
         LEFT JOIN advertsitems 
                   ON adverts.id = advertsitems.advertid 
GROUP BY adid
ORDER BY adid DESC
```

I tried to add COUNT(advertsitems.quantity) and but it doesn't count.

Comment: question structured poorly, but I guess you need `SUM`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pulling the `price` field from `advertsitems` without an aggregation.  This pulls the price from an arbitrary row.  The following query replaces this with the `min()`.  You might want `max()`, or `avg()`.

I'm assuming that all columns in the `select` except for price come from the `adverts` table.  They are prefixed with the appropriate alias.

Finally, I think what you want is `sum(quantity)`, not `count(quantity)`.

```
  SELECT a.title AS adtitle, 
         a.id AS adid, 
         a.image AS image,
         a.description, 
         sum(ai.quantity) as quantity
         min(price) as LowestPrice, 
         a.shipping, 
         a.customs, 
         a.createdate
  FROM adverts a LEFT JOIN
       advertsitems ai
       ON a.id = ai.advertid 
  GROUP BY a.id
  ORDER BY a.id DESC
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply! Im going to try your query and keep you updated, im going to my valentine right now, thanks!!

Comment: Thanks your query worked for me! I have a next question, posted above this post (was too long).